Run GitHub action with strategy matrix serially
I have a web application with a backend and a frontend. My backend can be started with different command-line options. I want to run different selections of my Cypress tests for different command-line options to start the backend.
I implement this using strategy matrix in my GitHub actions YAML file, like this:
...
jobs:
  testing:
    strategy:
      # Each job needs its own backend. Running backends in parallel requires using differnt ports.
      matrix:
        selection: [
          'default',
          'xml-storage'
        ]
    name: Unit tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
...

My tests fail because the jobs run in parallel. Each job tries to start the backend and I think these backends cannot run in parallel. I do not want the complexity of running each backend on a different TCP/IP port. How can I use the matrix feature without running my jobs in parallel?
EDIT: It is not true that my Cypress tests failed because they ran in parallel. I found other issues with my tests. Each test only accesses localhost which is a different host for each runner, so no network conflicts I expect. I am not an expert user of GitHub Actions however, so correct me if I am wrong.

Use max-parallel: 1, like this:
...
jobs:
  testing:
    strategy:
      # Each job needs its own backend. Running backends in parallel requires using differnt ports.
      max-parallel: 1
      matrix:
        selection: [
          'default',
          'xml-storage'
        ]
    name: Unit tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
...

EDIT: It is true that this causes the jobs to run serially, but there was no need to do so in the end. See the edited question.
